# passing a function to count occurences in a list in scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm trying to make a helper function that passes in a function such as even? or odd? and counts the number of occurences in a list. I seemingly developed the perfect logic but am getting an error (at the bottom), but cannot figure out why. I am passing '(cdr L) as a string, and taking the car of it to be used as an integer, why would it say given 'cdr? L is supposed to be a list and '(cdr L) should be a list.. why doesn't this work?

```
(define (fhelper F L )
    (if (> (length L) 1)
    (if (F (car L)) (+ 1 (fhelper F '(cdr L)))
                    (+ 0 (fhelper F '(cdr L))) )

    (if(F (car L))  1
                    0
                    )
                    )
    )

(fhelper even? '(1 2 3 4 ))
. . even?: contract violation
  expected: integer
  given: 'cdr
```

I tried testing to see that (even? (car '(1 2)) returns #f so I know its not a problem with my (F (car L)) section, so it almost seems as if the recursive call is applying F to '(cdr L) rather than using those as parameters, which I don't get because I tripple checked the documentation and it seems like that should work??

Comment: Think about what you're doing, ' can allow you to make "list literals", but everything inside the list will be considered a symbol, unless it's some numeric constant, string constant, character constant, or boolean constant. see -> http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Quoting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, you mustn't quote `(cdr L)` since you want the call to be performed.

You seem quite happy with your code but it's not very idiomatic; it should probably look like

```
(define (fhelper func lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      0
      (+ (if (func (car lst)) 1 0)
         (fhelper func (cdr lst)))))
```

or, as a tail-recursive procedure:

```
(define (fhelper func lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (count 0))
    (if (null? lst)
        count
        (loop (cdr lst)
              (if (func (car lst)) (add1 count) count)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `foldl` if you are familiar with it:

```
(define (fhelper f l)
  (foldl (λ (x xs) (if (f x) (add1 xs) xs))
         0
         l))
```